# How do I edit the title page of the Glasgow beamer theme?

Tags: beamer

I m trying  to use the Glasgow beamer theme.[Glasgow Theme](https://github.com/transientlunatic/glasgow-theme)

The title page looks like this[image: Title page]

I want to remove the Glasgow branding - both the box and the logo. I tried edit the style file, but I m not getting anywhere. Which lines should be commented out to remove the branding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @samcarter s answer, I had to comment out the following lines. (line 91 to 98)

```
% actual output of titlegraphic
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par%
    \newdimen\logoheight
    \setbox0=\vbox{\inserttitlegraphic}%
    \logoheight=\ht0 \advance\logoheight by \dp0 %
    \vspace*{-\logoheight}%
    \vspace*{-1em}%
```

Also had to uncomment the following line (line 101)

```
%\vfill
```

Answer (score 3):

These two lines draw the rectangle and the insert the logo:

```
\draw[university-blue, fill=university-blue] (0, -1.5) rectangle (5,0);
\node at (2.5,-0.75) {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{UoG_keyline.pdf}};
```